iPad connected via USB-C always disappears after Mac reboot
I have a new Mac Mini M2 (Sonoma) and an iPad 10th gen (iPadOS 17.7), connected using the USB-C cable the iPad came with.
I have the problem that after every reboot the iPad is gone on USB level: The iPad does not appear in Finder and idevice_id -l does not show a connected device.
Changing the USB-C cable has no effect on this problem.
If I connect an iPhone SE 3rd gen to the same USB-C port everything works as expected.
How can I make MacOS see the iPad without physically disconnect and reconnect the USB-C cable?
Updating the iPad OS to 18 is not an option.
